# What's the purpose of "step size" in a Julia-set code?

Tags: fractals

I'm not really sure what the step size (delta parameter) in a Julia set is meant for. What happens if I use step size 1 and what happens if i use step size 3? What's the difference afterwards?

Comment: Where do you see this parameter? Is it in a fractal rendering application?

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to your [identical post on math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022793/whats-the-task-of-step-size-in-a-julia-set), this probably affects the resolution of the image. It's hard to say for sure, though, without more information.